# Distribute commercial app by providing APK; restrict number of installation and distribution

Tags: android

I have developed a commercial Android app which is available in the Google Play Store. A company wants to roll out this app on about 200 devices of their employes. The easiest way for their IT administration would be the rollout of with a MDM-system, when I provide them the APK directly. This would mean, that I have no control over the further distribution and usage of the APK.
So my question are
- how can I make sure that the APK is distributed only within the organisation and is installed only on a certain number of devices? 
- what are the most common ways to cope with this problem? 
- are there any services, which I can use for a license-key check?

Comment: I'd never use a program that I couldn't switch to a replacement device.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, I would like to restrict the installation to a number of devices. This can be changed, if one of the devices has a defect..